# How can I add time range filter in Kibana Discover page?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I deployed Kibana 7.10.1 and Elasitcsearch 7.10.1. I am able to query from Kibana discover page. But I found the time range filter on the top right disappeared. How can I add it in the discover page?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found the reason is that I didn't pick up a timestamp index when create the index pattern in kibana.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you clicked in the search bar and when the search bar has the focus, the time picker disappears. Click outside of it and the time picker will be back.

I fell into the same trap a while ago and it didn't make sense to me. it's not really intuitive, but I guess the reason was to give as much screen real estate to the search bar while users are typing into it.

Comment: I have tried that but it still not showing.

Comment: Put a `*` in the search bar and click refresh, what happens? Then click outside the search bar again

Comment: It just refresh loading the logs but the time picker is still not showing

Comment: I feel your pain, been there as well, not intuitive. Can you click on KQL to the right of the search bar, change to Lucene and then back to KQL? The time picker is there, it's just hidden for no real reason and we just need to find the right click sequence :-)

Comment: I just tried that but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: I found the reason and added the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you update Kibana/Elastic.

You need to do `SHIFT` + click on reload button (in Mac: `CMD` + reload). Or you can use one of other ways that reload browser cache (e.g. open DevTools or use `ctrl`+`shift`+`delete`).